# simulink detect gcs if subsystem

Tags: if-statement, block, simulink, subsystem

I have this function, but it breaks when gcs is a subsystem.

```
function dest = save(path)
    dest = save_system(gcs,path)
end
```

i would want it to be something like:

```
function dest = save(path)
    item = gcs
    if(gcs.isSubsystem)
        dest = //do subsystem stuff
    else
        dest = save_system(gcs,path) 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to check this is

```
if strcmp(bdroot(gcs),gcs)
   % I'm the main model
else
   % I'm a subsystem
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dest = save(path)
    if isempty(strfind(gcs,'/'))
        dest = save_system(gcs,path)
    else
        //do subsystem stuff
    end
end
```